# Count distinct occurrences in all combinations of a column?

Tags: sql

I have a table containing occurrences of certain categories:

| USER ID | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- |
| A | Mobile |
| A | Website |
| A | e-commerce |
| B | Mobile |
| B | Website |
| C | e-commerce |

I would like to generate all possible combinations and count unique occurrences of User ID that fits this combination, such as:

| Categories | Counts |
| --- | --- |
| Mobile | 3 |
| e-commerce | 2 |
| Mobile, Website | 2 |
| Mobile, Onsite | 0 |
| Mobile, e-commerce | 1 |
| Mobile, Website, Onsite | 0 |
| Mobile, Website, Onsite, e-commerce | 0 |

... etc

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments; not sure what RMDBS you are on, but basically this is what you want

```
SELECT Category, COUNT(UserId) AS Counts
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Categroy
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* explicitly query for each set of combinations:

```
select category, count(*)
from t
group by category
union all
select t1.category || ',' || t2.category, count(*)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.category < t2.category
group by t1.category || ',' || t2.category
union all
select t1.category || ',' || t2.category ',' || t3.category, count(*)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.category < t2.category join
     t t3
     on t2.userid = t3.userid and t2.category < t3.category
group by t1.category || ',' || t2.category ',' || t3.category;
```

The above does what you want for up to 3 combinations.  You can add more similar subqueries for bigger combos.